# Calculator using PHP with logging to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have made a calculator in PHP and I need some feedback in terms of security and performance or any other general improvements.

You can download a zip file with all the contents from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hs1szco06cf2wlr/AAAKzK7ww1Jgs1IVNQEuUdQ4a?dl=0) if you wish to try it out for yourself! I rewrote the source and comments from Norwegian to English, except the .css file. I also put in a export of the MySQL database I used, so it's possible to test out the database if necessary.

The calculator also contains some "easter eggs". This is a school project of mine, and the teacher said that those would add a bonus. There are currently two:

1. Expand the log 5 times in a row (decreased for less clickyness)
2. Make a calculation that results in 1337

[image]

**My questions:**

1. Can something be improved with the filter function (security-wise)?
2. Is there other practices for making a PHP calculator with support for cos,sin and tan?
3. Are there any security flaws with the MySQL connection?
4. Is there any major performance issues?

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();  //start use of sessions on this document

//This is a function that gets the result of the Resultval session, if not set it returns 0
function getResIfSet() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["Resultval"])) {
        echo $_SESSION["Resultval"];
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">                                      <!--Set charset to UTF-8-->
        <title>Net-Calculator</title>                               <!--Set title of window-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_eng.css">    <!--Link to external stylesheet: style.css-->

        <!--Import JQuery-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    <!--Imorter JQuery biblotek for funksjonar.. etc-->

        <!--Start javascript with JQuery-->
        <script>

            //This functions just fades in the .box class when the page loads
            $(function() {
                $(".box").hide().fadeIn(500);
            });

            //Once document is ready..
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var position = false;   //Determines if the log is expanded or not
                var clicks = 0;         //Keeps a hold of how many times the #log_box is clicked (Easter egg)
                var res = "<?php getResIfSet(); ?>";    //The result value if user has calculated something (gets from php session *see top of document*)

                //if the result equals 1337 (Easter egg2)
                if (res == "1337") {
                    $(".mainwindow").animate({top: '-2000px'}, 2000);       //Make .mainwindow float far up
                    $("#elite").fadeIn(1000);                               //Fade in the #elite (img)
                    $("#elite_text").fadeIn(3000);                         //Fade in the #elite_text (paragaph)
                }

                //If the #log_box div is clicked..
                $("#log_box").click(function() {

                    //check the position value and expand/retract based on that
                    if (position === false) {

                        //make #log_box to auto height with animate.. i found this on the net, not that sure how it works tbh :D
                        $(this).animate({height: $("#log_box").get(0).scrollHeight});

                        position = true;    //invert the position variable

                        //This is the "OM NOM NOM" easter egg.. if the #log_box is expanded 5 times it turns it into a face!
                        if (clicks === 5) {
                            $(".mainwindow").fadeOut(5000);
                            $("h1").html("0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0");
                            $("#log_box").html("'OM NOM NOM!'<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>");
                            $("form").html("&nbsp;");
                            $(".box").css("display", "none");
                        } else {
                            //if clicks isnt 5.. increase it each time the #log_box expands
                            clicks++;
                        }

                    } else {
                        //make the #log_box to a single line only (compact)
                        $(this).animate({height: '20px'});

                        position = false;   //invert the position variable
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>

        <div id="mainwrap">                                 <!--MainWrap just centers the content on the webpage-->

            <div id="wrap2">                                <!--This is an additional div around the main wrap the 1337 image gets put in (Easter egg)-->

                <img src="1337.png" id="elite">             <!--Image gets loaded in, but is set to display:none in css by default unless 1337 is the result (Above)-->

                <p id="elite_text">Click <a href="index_eng.php">here</a> to go back!</p>  <!--Just a simple paragraph for the user to reload the page-->

                <div class="mainwindow">                    <!--This is the div where the "calculator" part is-->

                    <h1>Net Calculator</h1>                     <!--Create a text logo--> 

                    <form action="calculator.php" method="post">                            <!--Create the form to send data to calculator.php with the method post-->
                        <input id="input_bar" type="text" name="Input" autofocus>           <!--Make an text field with autofocus on, so the user dont need to click it-->         
                        <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Rekn ut!">        <!--Finally a submit button-->
                    </form>

                    <?php

                    //This section prints out the "boxes" with errors, answers or warnings

                    //Check if Result session and Type session is set.. if they are, print out a box with the Result.. and Type defines the color of the border.
                    if (isset($_SESSION["Result"], $_SESSION["Type"]) && !empty($_SESSION["Result"]) && !empty($_SESSION["Type"])) {

                        //Example: <div class="box answer"><h3> 3 + 3 = 6 </h3></div>
                        //Note: Type defines the border of the box
                        echo '<div class="box ' . $_SESSION["Type"] . '"><h3>' . $_SESSION["Result"] . '</h3></div>';

                        //Clear the used sessions (also Resultval for 1337 easter egg) so it wont carry over if the phage is refreshed
                        unset($_SESSION["Result"]);
                        unset($_SESSION["Resultval"]);
                        unset($_SESSION["Type"]); 
                    }

                    //This next if prints out a warning to the user, used to notify mysql database errors, but the calculator still works.. so it needs an extra box.

                    //Check if the warning session is set
                    if (isset($_SESSION["Warn"]) && !empty($_SESSION["Warn"])) {

                        //This box doesen't have changing borders, so its set to yellow by default, but the warning message changes
                        echo '<div class="box warn"><h3>' . $_SESSION["Warn"] . '</h3></div>'; 

                        //then clear the used session once done.
                        unset($_SESSION["Warn"]);                                               
                    }
                    ?>

                    <!--This is a work in progress (WIP)-->
                    <div id="log_box">
                        <h3>Log (Click me!)</h3>

                        Just static text for now, but i plan to add this in the future.<br>
                        3*3 = 15<br>
                        15-3 = 13<br>
                        20/5 = 4<br>
                        (30*2)/3 = 20<br>
                        10+10 = 20<br>
                        <br>
                        The log will only be local based on sessions, since the database is just to log whats happening..<br>
                        Imagine if everyone saw what other users were doing.. Thats why this is gonna be local only.

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**calculator.php**

```
<?php

//sets result session to the input of this function
function setResult($resultString) {
    $_SESSION["Result"] = $resultString;
}

//sets the warn session which indicates a warning (see index.php)
function setWarning($toWarn) {
    $_SESSION["Warn"] = $toWarn;
}

//sets the type of box to display (basicly color of the border)
function setBox($boxType) {

    //two things work here; answer and error
    $_SESSION['Type'] = $boxType;
}

//returns the user to the starts and ends the document
function returnToStart() {
    header("Location: index_eng.php");  //navigates the user back to index.php
    die();                          //end the document so it wont continue to load..
}

//get the input from the form index.php sent to this document.. if its empty.. set an error (bellow)
function getInput() {

    //if input session isnt set to anything...
    if (!empty($_POST["Input"]) && isset($_POST["Input"])) {

        return $_POST['Input']; //return the value if it is set

    } else {
        //if not..
        setResult("Error: Input is empty!");    //set the result to the error message
        setBox("error");                        //set the box type to error (red border)
        returnToStart();                        //and finally return the user back to index.php
    }
}

//filter the user input and error out if it doesent contain what it is supposed to contain
function filter($toFilter) {

    //first, remove all semicolons and whitespaces in the user input
    $toFilter = preg_replace('/[; ]+/', '', $toFilter);

    //then error out if input contains any other characters except those needed for sin(), cos() and tan()
    //this is to minimize harmful functions that you can write into the eval() function
    if (preg_match('/[bdefghjklmpqruvwxyzBDEFGHJKLMPQRUVWXYZ]+/', $toFilter)) {

        setResult("Error: Calculation contains unknown text. ");    //set the result to the error message
        setBox("error");                                            //set the box type to error (red border)
        returnToStart();                                            //and finally return the user back to index.php
    }

    return $toFilter;   //return the filtered input
}

//checks if the result string still contains text of any kind.. it it does thats an error..
function checkResult($toCheck) {
    if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $toCheck)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//log the result to the database
function logResult($input_filter, $result) {

    $servername = "127.0.0.1";      //server adress
    $username = "usernamehere";     //database username
    $password = "passwordhere";     //and password


    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    //check if the connection was sucsessfull..
    if ($conn->connect_error) {

        setWarning("Warning: Could not connect to database.");    //write a warning if it couldnt connect to the database

    } else {

        //create a query string that inserts values into the database kalk_log at table log
        $query = "INSERT INTO `calc_log`.`log` (`Calculation`, `Result`, `FromIP`) "
                . "VALUES ('$input_filter', '$result', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "');";

        //run the query against the conenction..if it fails, display a message indicating it failed
        if ($conn->query($query) === FALSE) {
            setWarning("Warning: Couldn't put calculation into database.");  //set warning message, no need for box type since its always yellow by default
            $conn->close(); //finally close the connection!
        }
    }

    $conn->close(); //close connection if it still isnt
}

//this is a unfinished function, supposed to log to a session and display it on the local log (the one with click me)
function localLog($calculation, $result){
    //TODO: do stuff here
}

//The main method for solving a calculation (calls the other methods)
function solve() {

    echo 'Calculating...';                              //just a indication that the process has started

    $input_raw = getInput();                            //get the input and put it into a local variable
    $input_filter = filter($input_raw);                 //filter the input and assign it to new variable
    $result = eval('return ' . $input_filter . ';');    //calculate using eval and input and put it to a variable

    //if the result still contains text.. dont display it and error out
    if (checkResult($result)) {
        setResult("Error: Result contains unknown text.");      //write error message
        setBox("error");                                        //set the box to type error
        returnToStart();                                        //return the user to the start
    }

    if (!empty($result) || $result === 0) {                     //checks if the result is empty (which means error from eval) i use the or (||) to still display even if the actual calculation is 0 (as in 51-51)
        $_SESSION["Resultval"] = $result;
        setResult($input_filter . ' = <u>' . $result . '</u>'); //set result session to what it returns with some html tags to format it correctly
        setBox("answer");

        //You can comment out logResult to supress the warnings on the website
        logResult($input_filter, $result);                      //log the result to the database using the input and result, rest it figures out itself.
        localLog($input_filter, $result);                       //log to a session to display on the webpage (Work In Progress)
    } else {
        setResult('Error: Something went wrong when solving.'); //if the result is empty.. set an error message as the result
        setBox("error");                                        //set box type to error..
    }

    returnToStart();                                            //and return to the start..
}

session_start();    //start use of sessions in the document
solve();            //call the main method (solve) and figure out the calculation from the user
```

**style.css**

```
#mainwrap{
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;

}

body{
    background: url(bakgrunn.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.mainwindow{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    border: gray solid 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.box{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

#log_box{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: gray solid 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
}

.error{
    border: red solid 3px;
}
.warn{
    border: yellow solid 3px;
}
.answer{
    border: greenyellow solid 3px;
}

#input_bar{
    width: 75%;
    border: black solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit_btn{
    width: 75px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit_btn:hover{
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

h1{
    color: black;
}

h3{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: grey solid 2px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

th,td{
    border: gray solid 2px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 7px;
}

#elite{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#elite_text{
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrap2{
    position:absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your 5 clicks easter egg actually takes 6 clicks to activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for ### and you will find my comments in your code

```
<?php

//sets result session to the input of this function
function setResult($resultString) {
    $_SESSION["Result"] = $resultString;
}

//sets the warn session which indicates a warning (see index.php)
function setWarning($toWarn) {
    $_SESSION["Warn"] = $toWarn;
}

//sets the type of box to display (basicly color of the border)
function setBox($boxType) {

    //two things work here; answer and error
    $_SESSION['Type'] = $boxType;
}

//returns the user to the starts and ends the document
function returnToStart() {
    header("Location: index_eng.php");  //navigates the user back to index.php

    // ### die indicates failure, use exit instead
    // ### die();                          //end the document so it wont continue to load..
    exit;
}

//get the input from the form index.php sent to this document.. if its empty.. set an error (bellow)
// ### think about your function names, a function called getInput that redirects to the start isn't really getting input is it?
// ### perhaps a better name, getInputOrReturnToStart()
function getInput() {

    //if input session isnt set to anything...

    // ### if (!empty($_POST["Input"]) && isset($_POST["Input"])) {
    // ### empty tests for isset as well
    if (!empty($_POST["Input"])) {

        return $_POST['Input']; //return the value if it is set

    } else {
        //if not..
        setResult("Error: Input is empty!");    //set the result to the error message
        setBox("error");                        //set the box type to error (red border)
        returnToStart();                        //and finally return the user back to index.php
    }
}

//filter the user input and error out if it doesent contain what it is supposed to contain
function filter($toFilter) {

    //first, remove all semicolons and whitespaces in the user input
    $toFilter = preg_replace('/[; ]+/', '', $toFilter);

    //then error out if input contains any other characters except those needed for sin(), cos() and tan()
    //this is to minimize harmful functions that you can write into the eval() function
    if (preg_match('/[bdefghjklmpqruvwxyzBDEFGHJKLMPQRUVWXYZ]+/', $toFilter)) {

        setResult("Error: Calculation contains unknown text. ");    //set the result to the error message
        setBox("error");                                            //set the box type to error (red border)
        returnToStart();                                            //and finally return the user back to index.php
    }

    return $toFilter;   //return the filtered input
}

//checks if the result string still contains text of any kind.. it it does thats an error..
function checkResult($toCheck) {

    // ### simplify code
//    if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $toCheck)) {
//        return true;
//    } else {
//        return false;
//    }

    return preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $toCheck);
}

//log the result to the database
function logResult($input_filter, $result) {

    // ### i realise this is a simple project, but it is best to store config data in constants at start of script
    // ### or in a separate file, not in the middle of your code
    $servername = "127.0.0.1";      //server adress
    $username = "usernamehere";     //database username
    $password = "passwordhere";     //and password


    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    //check if the connection was sucsessfull..
    if ($conn->connect_error) {

        setWarning("Warning: Could not connect to database.");    //write a warning if it couldnt connect to the database

    } else {

        // ### always escape sql parameters, as external parameters could have been interfered with
        // ### what if $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is not set?
        $remote_addr = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        //create a query string that inserts values into the database kalk_log at table log
        $query = "INSERT INTO `calc_log`.`log` (`Calculation`, `Result`, `FromIP`) "
            . "VALUES ('$input_filter', '$result', '" . $remote_addr . "');";

        //run the query against the conenction..if it fails, display a message indicating it failed
        if ($conn->query($query) === FALSE) {
            setWarning("Warning: Couldn't put calculation into database.");  //set warning message, no need for box type since its always yellow by default
            $conn->close(); //finally close the connection!
        }
    }

    // ### if there is a conn error you are trying to close a connection that was never opened?
    // ### Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
    $conn->close(); //close connection if it still isnt
}

//this is a unfinished function, supposed to log to a session and display it on the local log (the one with click me)
function localLog($calculation, $result){
    //TODO: do stuff here
}

//The main method for solving a calculation (calls the other methods)
function solve() {

    echo 'Calculating...';                              //just a indication that the process has started

    $input_raw = getInput();                            //get the input and put it into a local variable
    $input_filter = filter($input_raw);                 //filter the input and assign it to new variable
    $result = eval('return ' . $input_filter . ';');    //calculate using eval and input and put it to a variable

    //if the result still contains text.. dont display it and error out
    if (checkResult($result)) {
        setResult("Error: Result contains unknown text.");      //write error message
        setBox("error");                                        //set the box to type error
        returnToStart();                                        //return the user to the start
    }

    if (!empty($result) || $result === 0) {                     //checks if the result is empty (which means error from eval) i use the or (||) to still display even if the actual calculation is 0 (as in 51-51)
        // ### you have set functions for every other use of $_SESSION except this one??
        $_SESSION["Resultval"] = $result;
        setResult($input_filter . ' = <u>' . $result . '</u>'); //set result session to what it returns with some html tags to format it correctly
        setBox("answer");

        //You can comment out logResult to supress the warnings on the website
        logResult($input_filter, $result);                      //log the result to the database using the input and result, rest it figures out itself.
        localLog($input_filter, $result);                       //log to a session to display on the webpage (Work In Progress)
    } else {
        setResult('Error: Something went wrong when solving.'); //if the result is empty.. set an error message as the result
        setBox("error");                                        //set box type to error..
    }

    returnToStart();                                            //and return to the start..
}

session_start();    //start use of sessions in the document
solve();            //call the main method (solve) and figure out the calculation from the user
```

Comment: This peice doesent work.. $remote_addr = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); it needs to be $remote_addr = $conn->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

Answer (score 4):

## Signal-to-Noise ratio

Take this with a grain of salt, I realize your teacher might actually have made that a requirement. Generally, comments should not be used to describe *what* the code is doing, as the code itself does a pretty good job of doing that itself. Comments should be used to explain *why* your code is doing something, in cases where you are doing something unusual or that is not obviously clear.

For example, these comments are not useful:

```
<?php
session_start();  //start use of sessions on this document
//This is a function that gets the result of the Resultval session, if not set it returns 0
function getResIfSet() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["Resultval"])) {
        echo $_SESSION["Resultval"];
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

You could simply instead write `function getResultIfSet()` and the code would be self-explaining. Here is another example where the comments are not useful, and just make it harder to read:

```
//get the input from the form index.php sent to this document.. if its empty.. set an error (bellow)
function getInput() {
    //if input session isnt set to anything...
    if (!empty($_POST["Input"]) && isset($_POST["Input"])) {
        return $_POST['Input']; //return the value if it is set
    } else {
        //if not..
        setResult("Error: Input is empty!");    //set the result to the error message
        setBox("error");                        //set the box type to error (red border)
        returnToStart();                        //and finally return the user back to index.php
    }
}
```

Instead this would read better:

```
function getInput() {
    if (!empty($_POST["Input"]) && isset($_POST["Input"])) {
        return $_POST['Input'];
    } else {
        setResult("Error: Input is empty!");
        setBox("error");                    
        returnToStart();                    
    }
}
```

You did make some comments that were helpful, where the code itself was not clear why you are doing something unusual looking:

```
            //if the result equals 1337 (Easter egg2)
            if (res == "1337") {
                $(".mainwindow").animate({top: '-2000px'}, 2000);       //Make .mainwindow float far up
                $("#elite").fadeIn(1000);                               //Fade in the #elite (img)
                $("#elite_text").fadeIn(3000);                         //Fade in the #elite_text (paragaph)
            }
```

And here also:

```
                    //This is the "OM NOM NOM" easter egg.. if the #log_box is expanded 5 times it turns it into a face!
                    if (clicks === 5) {
                        $(".mainwindow").fadeOut(5000);
                        $("h1").html("0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0");
                        $("#log_box").html("'OM NOM NOM!'<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>");
                        $("form").html("&nbsp;");
                        $(".box").css("display", "none");
                    } else {
                        //if clicks isnt 5.. increase it each time the #log_box expands
                        clicks++;
                    }
```

As for the code itself, I think it looks good and well written, hopefully someone more experienced will find other things to say about it.

Comment: Yeah, the teacher demanded that we commented and explained everything we did. When i program for myself i don't write comments on self explaining prices of code. But i appreciate your feedback!

Comment: That's what I figured, not sure why some teachers ask that, I find it counter-productive and counter-intuitive. Glad you accepted the other answer as it is more constructive!